# How to use OpenTextSummarizer in vb6

Tags: text, vb6, summarization

i want to use OpenTextSummarizer.dll in visual basic 6 ! but i cant find   the right Declare !

DLL page : http://ots.codeplex.com/

Related topic : [How to use Open Text Summarizer API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850963/how-to-use-open-text-summarizer-api)

or if there is an alternative .

Thanks .

Comment: I don't think you can as it seems to be a net assembly without interopt. Not much point writing a program with no documentation.

Comment: If you want to use it you need to make a vb.net program that wraps it with a COM Server. See my post here on how to do that from command line and notepad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396122/appactivate-between-multiple-internet-explorer-instances/23434935. You'll need to change the name as sendmail is reserved Win 7 and later.